# match:shouldReinvitePlayer: only works for invititation matches?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I am trying to implement some basic reconnection functionality in my game by providing a `match:shouldReinvitePlayer:` call in my GKMatchDelegate.

It gets called everytime someone disconnects and returns YES everytime, but only when the match was created by invitation instead of auto-match, the disconnected player actually gets a new invite.

Is this expected (though undocumented) behaviour, is there some trick to it or is it maybe just Game Center's sandbox mode just acting weird?

Comment: I have a same issue.It seems that Game-Center question is been viewd very less.Please answer this if u get solution.I am having issue like if i am connected with 3 player and if 1player get disconneted than other also get disconneted from the game.How to avoid this disconnection of all the player from the game.Can we give a reinvtiation to the disconnected player in the game? if yes than how?

Comment: @shweta:
Well the method explicitly states that it only works for 2 player matches, so i guess you are pretty much out of luck there.

I still have not found a solution. The good news is that in iOS 6 you can leave your app for a short while without immediately being disconnected

Comment: Thanks for the reply.As i noticed that gamecenter questions are less view .but the game get disconnected as the one player out of 3get disconnected.I think game center will allow the rest other 2player to play its game.Instead of disconnection the all.